# failed to download package files check internet connection

Tags: software-center, internet

i recently installed ubuntu 12.04 by wubi installer.By giving right details of proxy in firefox i am able to access internet but when i try to download something ,ubuntu gives the error "failed to download package files check your internet connection.". How should this error be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem I used to get.

In terminal, enter the following command:

```
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=1
```

Un-select all the tick boxes and try again. the one that's not working can be isolated by re-enabling them one at a time and doing an update after each change.

Comment: Tried it,getting the same error

Comment: OK, try the link mentioned by Web-E